# Unable to resize button height in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-scale

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Demo")

class Application(Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid(sticky="ewns")
        self.feet = StringVar()
        self.meters = StringVar()
        self.create_widgets()
        
    def calculate(self):
        try:
            self.meters.set(int(0.3048 * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.master.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
        top=self.winfo_toplevel()              
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)       
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        b1=Button(self, text="7", command=self.calculate,bg="lime")
        b1.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky='we')
        
        ''' configuring adjustability of column'''
        self.columnconfigure(1, minsize=10, pad=0,weight=1)

        ''' configuring adjustability of rows'''
        self.rowconfigure(4, minsize=10, pad=0,weight=1)

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()on(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Here's the output

**before resizing [the same what appears after compiling]**

[image: before resizing [the same what appears after compiling]]

**after resizing**

[image: after resizing]

**As you can see, I am able to resize the width but not the height. Why so???**

Comment: how about `sticky='news'` to make sticky to all sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `sticky='news'` to make it sticky to all sides - top (**n**orth), right (**e**ast), left (**w**est), botton (**s**outh).

---

Almost the same code with few comments

```
import tkinter as tk  # popular method to make it shorter
#from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- classes ---

class Application(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid(sticky="ewns")
        self.feet = tk.StringVar()
        self.meters = tk.StringVar()
        self.create_widgets()
        
    def calculate(self):
        try:
            self.meters.set(int(0.3048 * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
        except ValueError:
            print("value error")  # it is good to see problems
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.master.resizable(width=True, height=True)
        top=self.winfo_toplevel()              
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)       
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="7", command=self.calculate, bg="lime")
        b1.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky='news')  # <-- `news`
        
        # configuring adjustability of column
        self.columnconfigure(1, minsize=10, pad=0,weight=1)

        # configuring adjustability of rows
        self.rowconfigure(4, minsize=10, pad=0,weight=1)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Demo")
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)